# I need to set the checkbox to enabled when its value is true

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to set like if the value of check box is coming true then check box show selected if the value comes false check box gets selected but what happening its value getting true from the backend I am storing value in the state rules but it's not getting enable and if the value is getting true also I am not able to check and unchecked checkbox when value is true checkbox not check when value it's true why it's happening not sure also I am trying to set onChange but getting confused how to set onchange

**value coming from backend**

```
NameMatch: true
Match: true
```

**SearchForm component**

```
export default function SearchForm() {

const { setRules, rules, fetchSearch } = useRule();
const [changeRuleSettings, setChangeRuleSettings] = React.useState(false);
React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchSearchRule();
  }, []);

const handleCheckBoxChange = (e) => {
    setRules((prevRules) => ({
      ...prevRules,
      [e.target.name]: !prevState[e.target.checked],
    }));
  };

 return (
 <Grid item xs={4}>
          <Box className={classes.formText}>
            <Checkbox
              style={style}
              name="NameMatch"
              checked={rules.NameMatch}
              color="primary"
              onChange={handleCheckBoxChange}
            />
            <Typography variant="subtitle2" noWrap={true}>
              Match
            </Typography>
          </Box>
        </Grid>
        
)
}
```

Comment: how are you storing value in `rules` state?

Comment: check code again i updated @miraj

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding the question correctly, you are asking what should the onChange function exactly do. So basically you need to switch the values of the property, that the Checkbox is dependent on. For example, if the backend returns :

```
exactNameMatch: true
partialNameMatch: true
```

Then for the first checkbox, when it is clicked, the value of **exactNameMatch** should be set to **false**. An example implementation would look something like this:

```
onChange={(e) => setRules((prevRules) => ({...prevRules, exactNameMatch: !prevRules.exactNameMatch}))}
```

For the second checkbox the **onChange** will be identical, with the small difference, that instead of **exactNameMatch** you would use **partialNameMatch**.

Another possibility is to implement the **handleCheckBoxChange** function like so:

```
  const handleCheckBoxChange = (e) => {
          setRules((prevRules) => ({...prevRules, [e.target.name]: !prevRules[e.target.name]}))
}
```

Where e.target.name is respectively **exactNameMatch** or **partialNameMatch**, based on the values you have passed to the name properties of the Checkbox component. Hope I managed to understand your problem correctly and actually help you!

Comment: what I need to set in prevState mean I can see you are calling prevState but what you are storing in it

Comment: Well, have you imported useState into the component?

Comment: yeah actualy i set my api in other component and importing link this       const { setRules,rules, initiateRules, fetchSearchRule } = useRule();

Comment: Show a bit more of your code, because I am struggling to understand what exactly is the situation.

Comment: So I have edited my code just a little for the handleCheckBoxChange function, instead of prevState, there should be prevRules. Other then that the problem is that you are trying to create a custom hook (useRule). In order to use the  **rules** **setRules** **fetchData** from the hook, you need to return them. Can you show the full code of the useRule hook.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233071/discussion-between-himanshu-rathi-and-xderty).